# despite defaultvalue being set, no value shows up in database

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
 <p>Special Meal Request:<br />
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="dietaryveg" value="yes" />Vegetarian
      </label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="dietaryglut" value="yes" />Gluten-Free
      </label>
```

This is what I decided to go with for a form I created. I didn't use radio buttons because I only want one checkbox; I didn't give the checkboxes the same names because they are different columns in the database, since a user could need both a vegetarian meal AND a gluten free meal.

However, when I pull up my database in mysql workbench, unchecked boxes still show up with no value in the column. I tried then to put a hidden checkbox with a value of no and it's the default checked, etc. But then both values show up as no in the database.

Now, I realize that php only cares about a checked box value, and not an unchecked box value- but I would think that if there is a default value in my database, that should be in there, much like a NULL, wouldn't it?

I really don't want to have a completely separate table just for rows of food preferences- I'm sure that there's just something that I'm missing.

Could I get some advice on the best way to handle this one?

Comment: Default values will only be used for new inserts. If you add a default value after rows have been inserted, the existing rows will not be affected. Could this be the problem? Also, note that if you specify the field in the field list for the insert, it will have a corresponding value in the value list and this value will be used, even if it is empty (an empty string is still a string) - you would need to omit the fields that were missing from the POST data from the query in order to use the default value or you can pass `NULL` as long as the field in the DB doesn't permit NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing something like : `(isset($_POST['dietarygut']))` and it is not set, then the value will be `NULL` and uploaded to the db. Post your PHP script

Answer (score 0):

What do you consider to be your default value?  With HTML check boxes, the `value` attribute does *not* mean a default value, but rather the value the box will send along if it's checked.  If one is not/none are checked, the value 'yes' will not be sent along.

Like mlishn said in his answer, you'll need to programatically check if one/both of the boxes are set, and if so, insert those values.